# About different ramayna by different authers and different thinking

Tags: ramayana

There are so many versions of Ramayan by different authors
Is there any difference we can't accept?

Which one is correct and most accurate?

Kin authers ne supernatural power Ke Karan Ramayan likhi...kya other version only modification h ?

In Ramayan life of RAM is very tough, and even each character's life was tough, is it possible, can we follow their path in today's circumstances, and in which cases?

Comment: Valmiki, tulasi Das etc are rishis and were able to write the ramayana with the aid of their gurus' blessings and supernatural powers of "darsana". It is said kavi krAnta darzanaH. There is slight difference in the renditions due to differences in goals of the author and due to differences in darshana and differences in the unfolding of events in various kalpas. Cannot comment about others' work but valmiki and tulasi ramayana are definitely sacred. Whether the outcome is favorable or not, we must strive to follow in the footsteps of bhagwan.

Comment: You are right we should follow but still it's way too tough ,even we can't always tell truth ,we have to lie no matter what in some cases.